# Need help reading a UML Diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

[image]

Hello, I've been asked to create a class using the UML Diagram provided above.I'm not quite sure how to read it. I've currently created:

```
using System;

namespace Packets
{
    enum PacketType { ChatMessage, PrivateMessage, ClientName };
    public class Packet
    {
        public PacketType packetType
        {
        }

        Packet:ChatMessagePacket
        {
            public string message;
        public void ChatMessagePacket(string message)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But this is incorrect. I'm not sure about the `get ~set` or `ChatMessagePacket:Packet`.
Any help is much appreciated.
Many thanks,
Ben.

Comment: your input UML diagram is invalid

Comment: Please also tag the language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

That `get~set` is an invention of the UML author and no standard. It would be correct to specify both the getter and setter separately as operations. But basically it would be enough to either type an attribute or use a role with an association towards the enumeration. Making getter/setter is merely an implementation detail and bringing that into the UML makes the design just confusing. Often UML modelers overdo it and (probably) think that coders are just monkeys which they are not.